# Format cells (row height, merge) based on variables?

Tags: excel, variables, formatting, vba

I realize this is a long shot but why not. I want to create Sheet1 with raw data:

```
Class |  Info
1     | Subject
2     | Topic
3     | Unique data 
3     | Unique data 
3     | Unique data 
1     | Subject
2     | Topic
3     | Unique data
```

Then in Sheet2 I want to get the Class# and format it accordingly:

```
-If Class=1 then: 1 row, Top and Bottom border
-If Class=2 then: Merge 2 rows of cells, text = 16pt, top & btm border
-If Class=3 then: Merge 3 rows of cells, text = 24 pt, top & btm border
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this on Excel? Thanks

**Edit**
To clarify: I'm trying to make a pharm list for class without having to spend several days of straight formatting. 
 
This is the layout I would like to have in Sheet2
[image: This is the layout I would like to have in Sheet2]

Here is the raw data from Sheet1, that Sheet2 pulls from
[image]

Comment: You can only do this using `VBA`. Are you open to explore that alternative. If yes, have you tried something out? Please post it and clarify what is your issue.

Comment: I'm open to anything! I have no idea how to use VBA and wouldn't even know where to begin. I've edited the original question with clarification of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: If you are exporting from a database you'd be better off pulling the data and having it exported to worksheets seamlessly by a macro.

Comment: Your example doesn't match your description. This way our submissions (if there will be any) won't fit your expectations but may provide guidelines.

Comment: Right, just need to know if I can, at any level, format cells based one one variable. I can do the rest if I just know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub ert()
'ws As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("Munka2") 'name of the worksheet with data
'if you don't start from scratch every time then a cleaning sub reference should be here
i = 1
LastRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'the last row in the worksheet
While i <= LastRow
If Not ws.Range("A" & i).Value2 = "" Then 'if the class value is specified and not a dummy row
Select Case ws.Range("A" & i).Value2 'class value
        Case 1 'if it's class1
            With ws.Range("B" & i & ":I" & i) 'merges from B to I column, top and bottom border, grey background
                .Merge
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
                '.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThin
                '.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
                .Interior.Color = RGB(180, 180, 180)
                '.Font.Name = "Calibri" 'not specified, you may vary them along the lines of: see below
                '.Font.Size = 11
                '.Font.Bold = True
                '.Font.Italic = True
            End With
        Case 2 'inserts a row then merges the two rows from B to D, adds top, bottom, left and right borders, font size: 16 pt
            ws.Range(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1).Rows.Insert 'inserts a row after this one
            With ws.Range("B" & i & ":D" & i + 1)
                .Merge
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThin
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
                '.Interior.Color = RGB(180, 180, 180)
                '.Font.Name = "Calibri" 'not specified, you may vary them along the lines of: see below
                .Font.Size = 16
                '.Font.Bold = True
                '.Font.Italic = True
            End With

        Case 3 'inserts two rows, merges B to C, all four borders, font size: 24 pt
            ws.Range(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1).Rows.Insert 'inserts two rows after this one
            ws.Range(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1).Rows.Insert
            With ws.Range("B" & i & ":C" & i + 2)
                .Merge
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThin
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
                '.Interior.Color = RGB(180, 180, 180)
                '.Font.Name = "Calibri" 'not specified, you may vary them along the lines of: see below
                .Font.Size = 24
                '.Font.Bold = True
                '.Font.Italic = True
            End With
        Case Else
            'if there is a row in which class is defined but doesn't match your cases then it should warn you
            MsgBox "You have messed up something"
            ws.Select
            ws.Range("A" & i).Select
End Select

End If
i = i + 1
LastRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'the number of rows may have changed
Wend
End Sub
```

With a sample input

```
   | A | B
1  | 1 | Hyper-Thyroid State
2  | 2 | Antithyroid Drugs
3  | 3 | Thioureylenes
4  | 4 | Propylthiouracil
```

My output was
[image: output]